# how to access controls inside asp repeater control

Tags: asp.net

I am having form which allows user to update their profile and contact information.I have created this form using asp:repeater control inside a div tag.I am having 4 div tags inside that having repeater control which contains other controls such as text boxes and drop down list.I just want to know,how i can access controls inside repeater control.I am giving the code:

```
<tr>
<td class="directorytdWidth">
Gender:
</td>
<td class="directoryTdPadding">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtGender" runat="server"    Width="100px" Text='<%#Eval("gender")%>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioGender" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" Visible="false">
<asp:ListItem Text="Male" Value="M"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Female" Value="F">  </asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="directorytdWidth">
Address:
</td>
<td class="directoryTdPadding">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd" runat="server" Width="200px"     Text='<%#Eval("candiAddress")%>'
TextMode="MultiLine" Height="75px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="directorytdWidth">
Country:
</td>
<td class="directoryTdPadding">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("countryName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpCountry" runat="server"    SelectedValue='<%#Eval("countryName")%>' Width="150px" Height="24px" Visible="false"
AutoPostBack="true"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpCountry_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="directorytdWidth">
State:
</td>
<td class="directoryTdPadding">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server"    Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("stateName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpState" runat="server" SelectedeValue='<%#Eval("stateName")%>' Width="150px" Visible="false" Height="24px"
AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpState_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="directorytdWidth">
City:
</td>
<td class="directoryTdPadding">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Width="150px"     Text='<%#Eval("cityName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpCity" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="24px" Visible="false"
AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="directorytdWidth">
Postal Code:
</td>
<td class="directoryTdPadding">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPostalCode" runat="server"    Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("pincode")%>'></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="directorytdWidth">
Landline:
</td>
<td class="directoryTdPadding">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLandline" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("landline")%>'></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="directorytdWidth">
Mobile Number:
</td>
<td class="directoryTdPadding">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMobile" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("mobile")%>'></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="directorytdWidth">
Date of Birth:
</td>
<td class="directoryTdPadding">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDob" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("dob")%>'></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpYear" runat="server" Visible="false" Height="24px" Width="80px"
AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpMonth" runat="server"    Height="24px" Width="80px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpMonth_SelectedIndexChanged"
AutoPostBack="true" Visible="false">
<asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">January</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">February</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="3">March</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="4">April</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="5">May</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="6">June</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="7">July</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="8">August</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="9">September</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="10">October</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="11">November</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="12">December</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpDate" runat="server"    Height="24px" Width="50px" Visible="false"
AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="directorytdWidth">
Email Address:
</td>
<td class="directoryTdPadding">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="150px" Text='<%#Eval("altEmail")%>'></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
```

In this I am having drop down selected index changed event,so how to fire this event
and also I want define functions which can be accessible in drop down event.Because when i define functions I am unable to get controls inside repeater control.So please give me any solution for this.Thanks in advance....

Comment: posting few code which is relevant will get you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what controls do you want to access, but

1) make them runat="server" and give them ID

2) add event handler to repeater for `ItemCreated`, or `ItemDataBound` events

3) access control like this:

```
    void R1_ItemCreated(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
          var label = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("YourItemId")  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot access the dropdown events once they are in the repeater control. you can perform actions on buttons using `CommandName` and `CommandArgumnent` in `ItemCommand` event of repeater.

however you can do a workaround. bring the dropdown out of repeater , generate its `SelectedIndexChanged` event and `AutoPostback="true"`. Then put back in repeater. Now in its event in code behind you can perform your operations. I once did this but this isn't good way.